# [InvalidOperationException: Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/activeprocess'.]

Tags: asp.net, web-services

when i tried pasting te url to webservice hovewver it works fine when i click on invoke button..

```
  [InvalidOperationException: Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/activeprocess'.]
       System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.CoreGetHandler(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response) +489333
       System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String verb, String url, String filePath) +212
       System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, String url, String pathTranslated) +47
       System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHttpHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath path, String pathTranslated, Boolean useAppConfig) +226
       System.Web.MapHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +145
       System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: Can you show code, please

Comment: code is to display the remote machine process using WMI..and it works fine..in webservice i hav written webmethod named activeprocess.On click of the link and on invoke it works fine.BUt when i copy the same link or refresh the page it throws me the above error.is there any method to directly call the webmethod via URL??

Comment: did you find a solution? I'm having this same error as well